キャリア? What definition is correct?

天道と伊波が地図を覗き込みながら協議している。様々なシチュエーションを想定しながら意見を述べるあたり、さすがのキャリアというべきか。

The character is watching his two colleagues discuss about the next plan for their mission...
I understand the sentence up to this point

天道と伊波が地図を覗き込みながら協議している。様々なシチュエーションを想定しながら意見を述べる

However, I'm stumbled on the very last implication:
あたり、さすがのキャリアというべきか。
The word has various meaning but maybe it's "personal history; professional experience​"? I assume あたり here is acting similar to のは at least

It means "a job."

Are perhaps 天道 and 伊波 government officers?

Yes, they work in government

Then I guess it probably means "cadre track bureaucrats", but no decisive clue. Is there any information about character's background available?

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/キャリア_(国家公務員)

@broccoli forest not much, honestly they are part of a special government unit that hunts spirits

Why not simply interpret it as "(professional) careers"? Then the sentence simply means something like "(Their way of working) truly showcases their seasoned expertise/careers/experience!" Even if they are not キャリア公務員, there's nothing strange about this sentence.


様々なシチュエーションを想定しながら意見を述べるあたり、さすがのXというべきか。

In this construction, X is supposed to be a description of a person or a group of people which is the implicit subject of the sentence inherited from the previous sentence (=天道と伊波が). Typically, it's a job, a role or a title.
The meaning is something along the lines of "how they [competently] do this and that demonstrates that they are true X". In Japanese, the "they are" part is implicit. あたり acts as a hedge to say it's no more than an observation of the speaker/narrator (thus making it more like a line by a character rather than an omniscient and transparent narrator).
If they are hired like any other bureaucrats in the fictional universe, and the government system is closely modeled after the actual Japanese system, then キャリア short for career-track bureaucrats is not strange in the fictional universe. If such background information has not been provided to the reader, perhaps the author tries to provide that here implicitly by using the phrase. The implication is that there are officially career-track employees with a (competitive) career path to the top job, and the rest with no such path of promotion.
The other interpretation seems less likely. If I wanted to mention experience in this construction, I would use something along the lines of "experienced people" rather than "experience" - 経験者 or 熟練者 rather than キャリア.
